# Unexpected array after looping over set

Tags: python, data-structures, error-handling, set, iteration

I'm currently using a graph to find successors from a BFS algorithm. Due to the nature of my grid, at some point my successors will be doubled. To get rid of the doubles, I change my list to a set and continue to iterate. This goes well till the last iteration in which an unexpected array pops up, instead giving an empty list. I've looked this problem up and people suggest to not change the data structure while the loop is running, but after maintaining the data structure as a list, the problem still occurs. I'll provide you with my original script, which changes the list to set.

Below a small portion of my code. I've used print statements to see whats going on.

```
predecessors_storage = [source]
successors_storage = []
total_dredged_sediment = 0

 while (len(predecessors_storage) > 0):
   print('predecessors storage before loop', predecessors_storage)
   for predecessor in predecessors_storage:
      successors_storage += list(H.successors(predecessor))
   successors_storage = set(successors_storage)

   for successor in successors_storage:
      depth_successor, dredged_sediment = generate_cell_equilibrium(H, successor, depth_array, dDepth)
      depth_array[successor] = depth_successor
      total_dredged_sediment += dredged_sediment

   predecessors_storage = successors_storage
   successors_storage = []
```

the printed statements:

```
predecessors storage before loop [3]
predecessors storage before loop {9, 6}
.... (this goes on for a while)
predecessors storage before loop {59, 60}
predecessors storage before loop {62}
predecessors storage before loop [array([37, 39, 45, 47, 50, 51, 22, 54, 25, 26])] <- unexpected
```

Does any of you how to tackle this problem? thanks in advance!

EDIT: this is the reproducible code. The odd thing is, is that this one does work, i.e. is does not produce a random array at the end. I've created this code in a separate file

```
import networkx as nx 
import numpy as np

source = (0, 0)
G = nx.grid_2d_graph(6, 6)
bfs_edges_source = list(nx.edge_bfs(G, source))    
H = nx.create_empty_copy(G, False).to_directed()
H.add_edges_from(bfs_edges_source)

predecessors_storage = [source]
successors_storage = []

total_dredged_sediment = 0

while len(predecessors_storage) > 0:
    print(predecessors_storage)
    for predecessor in predecessors_storage:
        successors_storage += list(H.successors(predecessor))
    successors_storage = set(successors_storage)

    predecessors_storage = successors_storage
    successors_storage = []
```

Comment: The only time `predecessors_storage` is (and can be) a **list** is when the loop makes its first iteration. So I guess you call this code multiple times. You can confirm this by placing a `print("------")` *before* the outer loop. Please provide code with which the problem can be *reproduced*.

Comment: Hi! I've added the reproducible code to the question after the 'EDIT'

Comment: Sorry, but when I run that code, I don't see any output of an array or list. Only sets. Like you wrote it doesn't produce the problem, so that is not *reproducible*. I'm voting to close this question as "not reproducible".

Comment: Yes that's also what I get. I think there is something wrong in my complete code, which interferes with this loop. I have no idea how it can be that the my original while loop (which is located in a script with multiple functions) produces a random array